# Detect Creation or Update of AWS Role, and trigger a lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am trying to figure out a way to trigger a Lambda on the creation or update or a Role in AWS.

The use case is that when a Role is created, we need to update our Identity Server with the new or changed Role.

I'm looking at cloud trail, and having mixed results. I could schedule a lambda to run, but I'd prefer to make it more real time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like going CloudTrail's way is exactly what AWS suggested.

What issue you got into?

> AWS CloudTrail saves logs to an S3 bucket (object-created event).
>
> Amazon S3 detects the object-created event.
>
> Amazon S3 publishes the s3:ObjectCreated:* event to AWS Lambda by
>   invoking the Lambda function, as specified in the bucket notification
>   configuration. Because the Lambda function's access permissions policy
>   includes permissions for Amazon S3 to invoke the function, Amazon S3
>   can invoke the function.
>
> AWS Lambda executes the Lambda function by assuming the execution role
>   that you specified at the time you created the Lambda function.
>
> The Lambda function reads the Amazon S3 event it receives as a
>   parameter, determines where the CloudTrail object is, reads the
>   CloudTrail object, and then it processes the log records in the
>   CloudTrail object.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Ensure a log metric filter and alarm exist for IAM policy changes and similar.

Alarm can put message to SNS for example.

Lambda can be triggered by that SNS message.

Real-time monitoring of API calls can be achieved by directing CloudTrail Logs to CloudWatch Logs and establishing corresponding metric filters and alarms. It is recommended that a metric filter and alarm be established changes made to Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies.